# Configuring Nexus OSS as P2 repo

Tags: nexus, tycho, p2

I have have an internal Nexus OSS server with dozens of  regular Maven jar artifacts in Inhouse, Snapshots and various proxied repos.

I have also installed the Nexus P2 Repository Plugin and the P2 Bridge Plugin (2.6.3-01) and the Nexus Unzip Plugin (0.12.0). I can browse to the .meta/p2 folder of our group repository, but it is currently empty.

My understanding is that I should be able have one (or a combination) of the aforementioned plugins automagically convert the regular jars into bundles  (or maybe I need to manually run the Felix bundle maven plugin to redeploy each of them) and then make them available to Tycho.

What I don't understand is which repo I should be pointing the P2 plugins at in the capabilities tab and the update repo/meta inf scripts configuration - is it necessary to do each hosted/proxy repo individually or can I do it for the Public group repo?

Also, how can I easily verify which bundles/plugins are available via the P2 repo?

Comment: The unzip plugin allows you to browse into zip archives in the Maven repository it is shadowing. It doens't do any of the magic conversion you mentioned. I don't know the other plugins.

Comment: I have the unzip plugin installed but I'm not sure how to use it from tycho. Are there examples anywhere?

Comment: If you build a zipped p2 repository with Maven (e.g. Tycho's `eclipse-repository` packaging type) and deploy that project to Nexus, you can use the unzip plugin to access the deployed p2 repository from any p2 repository client, e.g. another Tycho build. For details, see the [unzip plugin setup instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin).

Comment: Doesn't the `eclipse-repository` build need to find the `bundle-pomfirst` in Nexus?

Comment: For the unzip plugin, it doesn't matter at all how the zipped p2 repository is built.